# Dell Inspiron 6000 network issues

Tags: wireless, networking, drivers, broadcom, inspiron

I cant see wireless connections which I should and could with windows 7 and a wired connection seems unstable, IE shows a connection then I try to use it and it disconnects.

I have tried to update the drivers and I see these odd problems.

Broadcom Corporation: Wireless 1370 WLAN mini-PCI card;
this device is using an alternate drive;
Broadcom 802.11 luna STA wireless driver....

And THEN....

Unknown:Unknown
This Device is using a manually-installed driver

I also just got this from trying to read the forms, not sure what to do with the info though

Broadcom Corporation BCM4318 [AirForce One 54g] 802.11g Wireless LAN Controller [14e4:4318] (rev 02)

on the unknown one the only check-able option is to continue running on that driver

Answer (score 0):

I have a 6000 also, and I believe what I did was

`sudo apt-get install linux-firmware linux-firmware-nonfree`

it shows up in ifconfig as eth1.

Comment: Thanks but when I tried that and got dpkg was interupted run sudo dpkg --configure-a. Which I did and got a segmentation fault

Comment: @forrest dpkg should not be crashing. Do you have bad hardware? Or corrupt drive (run `fsck` on it)? Or bad memory?

Comment: How do you run fsck